# Erro ao abrir formulário - Delphi

Tags: delphi, formulário

Possuo uma aplicação que foi desenvolvida em Delphi7 e preciso realizar uma alteração em um determinado formulário, porém ao tentar abrir esse formulário para realizar essas alterações a seguinte janela de erro me é exibida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Devido a ser uma aplicação já antiga (que não fui eu quem desenvolveu) e pelo fato de não ter muito domínio da linguagem, não imagino como posso resolver tal erro, seria uma biblioteca que preciso adicionar?

Comment: dá me a parecer que não tem o componente instalado

Comment: @Tmc, sabe como posso fazer para instalar tal componente para validar se esse é a falha?

Comment: tente instalar isso http://www.micrel.cz/RxLib/dfiles.htm

Comment: @Tmc Eu olhei ai mas não encontrei o local para baixar a biblioteca

Comment: Já editei o link

Comment: @Tmc, Tu saberia me dizer qual arquivo devo instalar?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65831/discussion-between-tmc-and-r-santos).

Comment: Qual versão do Delphi que está rodando esse código legado? Houveram mudanças em alguns métodos entre versões, acredito que é isso que esta acontecendo aí, poderia passar o código da linha aonde esse erro ocorre?

Comment: A versão é Delphi7, consegue me passar teu email @Paz?

Comment: pazzinimurilo@gmail.com

Comment: Esse componente é da RxLib, já descontinuada. Se o formato do dfm for texto, você pode tentar (fazendo os devidos backups) alterar a classe para TDBLookupCombo (tanto no dfm quanto no pas). Possivelmente, causará erros com propriedades que eventualmente não existam em EDBLookupCombo; então basta remover no dfm a linha que gera o erro.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do @Jonathan Cani: Instale O `RXLib` que esse componente faz parte desse pacote. Baixe [aqui](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rxlib/files/RxLib%202.7.7%20for%20Delphi%206-2010/) ou substitua o componente por outro semelhante...

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro ocorre pois provavelmente não possui o componente/biblioteca instalados, caso não tenha, Você deve marcar a opção ignorar todos, para que o Delphi não remova automaticamente a declaração do objeto do seu código fonte.

Se você acessar o menu "Project" e utilizar as opções "Compile All Projects" e "Build All Projects", há uma chance do seu projeto possuir o componente, mas não tê-lo compilado.

Em "Component" você pode tentar utilizar os recursos existentes para apontar o endereço do seu componente.

Em "Project" você pode tentar acessar a opção "Project Options" e em "Packages" verificar se o seu componente está selecionado para uso, ou então tentar adiciona-lo a lista novamente.

Comment: Só lembrando que tem você tem que saber qual é a biblioteca que esse componente faz parte...